# Option<Integer> vs Supplier<Integer>

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

Q) what is the need of Optional functional interface ?

I do understand the need of  Optional is to avoid null check .. but still need to do .isPresent() check ??

2)would we have achieved the same thing using Supplier and do .get() on the instance when ever we needed the value??

```
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1,2,4);
currently--> Optional<Integer> opt =intList.stream().reduce((a,b)->a*b);
                    int result =opt.get();


suggestion--> Supplier<Integer> sup=intList.stream().reduce((a,b)->a*b);
               int result =sup.get();
```

why introduce something new if supplier could have done the same thing.? or just have any one of them ??

Comment: `Optional` is not an interface but a class and has more methods than just `get`.

Comment: How does the Supplier tell you whether the value is present?

Answer (score 0):

The stream may be empty, in which case there's no meaningful value to obtain from the Supplier.
That's the reason why you get an Optional, and not a Supplier.

The basic contract of an Optional is that there may, or may not be a value present.

The base contract of a Supplier is that values can be retrieved on demand.
The only way to express that the Supplier has no available value is to throw an exception, what we could and certainly want to avoid, as a user of the Supplier.